# Subject and object in a sentence with は and が: 確かに妻が「ついていてほしい」と言った看護婦さんは

Tags: grammar, meaning, parsing

> 確かに妻が「ついていてほしい」と言った看護婦さんは、仕事の仕方が他の人とは[一味]{ひとあじ}違っていることに気がついた。

I'm a bit confused about は and が in this sentence and I can't guess which one is the subject or object.

1. I tried parsing the sentence like this:
   妻が/////「ついていてほしい」と言った看護婦さんは

妻 が is the subject

「ついていてほしい」と言った看護婦さんは -> it's like the person who said 「ついていてほしい」 is 看護婦(？)(？)

Or:

2. 妻が「ついていてほしい」と言った/////看護婦さんは
   妻が「ついていてほしい」と言った adverbially modifies 看護婦

A nurse that my wife wants to take care of her.

Which one is correct?

Comment: It's 2. 妻が「ついていてほしい」と言った modify 看護婦. It means a nurse that my wife want her to take care of someone.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> 確かに`???`に気がついた。
>   Admittedly, I noticed `???`.

Someone may say this 確かに modifies 違っている, but I think it's easier to think this 確かに as a [sentence adverb](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjunct_(linguistics)#Examples). The main topic of the whole sentence is 私 (i.e., 妻's husband), which is omitted. `???` is a fairly long noun sentence, where 看護師 is the topic.

> 確かに[看護師さん**は**仕事の仕方**が**違っていること]に気がついた。
>   Admittedly, I noticed [that the nurse was different in her way of working].

"AはBが違う" literally means "As for A, B is different" or more naturally, "A is different in B".

> 確かに[看護師さんは仕事の仕方が**他の人とは一味**違っていること]に気がついた。
>   Admittedly, I noticed [that the nurse was *somewhat* different *from others* in her way of working].

は in 他の人とは is contrastive (and thus optional). 一味 is a nuanced word meaning "small but significant", "somehow", etc.

> 確かに妻が「ついていてほしい」と言った看護婦さんは、仕事の仕方が他の人とは一味違っていることに気がついた。
>   Admittedly, I noticed that the nurse **whom my wife wanted to look after [me/you/our son/etc]** was somewhat different from others in her way of working.

`妻が「ついていてほしい」と言った` *adjectivally* (not *adverbially*) modifies 看護師 as a relative clause. (lit. "the nurse about which my wife said 'I want her to be with [you/me/our son/etc]' ")

So-called thematic は can appear in a noun clause like this (e.g, 彼**は**学生だと思う = I think he is a student), but not in a relative clause which modifies another noun (e.g. [×]彼**は**食べたケーキ [○]彼**が**食べたケーキ). That's why が is used after 妻 and は is used after 看護師.

Comment: So the subject in this sentence is 看護婦？ but how do you know that 看護婦 is the subject and 妻 adjectivally modifies 看護婦 is it because と**言った**ーた(？) and "whom my wife wanted to be with **me**"(me refer to 私->主人？) its not "whom my wife want to be with"?

Comment: @Devina Muljono The subject in this sentence is 私, the hidden topic. ..違っていることに、（私は）気がついた。

Comment: Admittedly , I(主人) noticed that the nurse **whom my wife wanted to be with me(主人) or me(妻)？** was somewhat different from others in her way of working.

Comment: @DevinaMuljono See the edit in my answer as to why I thought 妻 is not the topic of the sentence. I assumed the context where the ill person is the husband himself (=the speaker of the sentence in question), but it can be anyone who is ill in this context ("with our daughter", "with our boss", ...)